# Programmatically update an entity reference field

Tags: 8, entities

I know I can update (or set a value for) an entity reference field in Drupal 7 with code similar to the following.

```
 $node['field_code_used_by'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = $id;
```

I want to programmatically set a value for my user entity reference field in Drupal 8.

I tried with `$node->field_code_used_by->setValue(1);` and `$node->field_code_used_by->entity->value = 1;` but neither of them worked.

How can I set the value for an entity reference field?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to use code similar to the following.

```
    $node = Node::load($nid);     
    $node->field_code_used_by->target_id = $user_id;
    $node->save();
```

For a multiple-value field, to add the value to the end of the list, use the following code.

```
$node->field_code_used_by[] = ['target_id' => $user_id];
```

Another way is setting the `entity` property with the entity object, as in the following code.

```
    $node = Node::load($nid);
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $node->field_code_used_by->entity = $user;
    $node->save();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless the parent node already exists. When assigning the target_id or entity property to a new, unsaved parent node, the relationship is not saved. (Possibly also doesn't work when assigning to an NULL entity ref field, but i haven't tested that.) Anyone know how to address this case?

Comment: @aaronbauman did you got any solution to it ?

Comment: @echo i don't remember how or if i worked around this. If my description of the behavior is accurate, this is a bug. If there isn't an open issue on drupal.org for it, there should be

Comment: @aaronbauman https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2707017#comment-11872624 helped me to make that work with new node. So doesn't seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 19):

Like in D7 the main property of a reference field in D8 is still the `target id`:

```
$node->field_code_used_by->target_id = $user_id;
```

The `entity` property is a computed value. If you put an object in this value, drupal will convert it back to the id before saving it to the dababase.

**Multivalue fields**

Add an item to a multivalue field:

```
$node->field_code_used_by[] = ['target_id' => $user_id];
```

The property `target_id` is not necessary, because it is the main property and  used by default. So for most fields you can add a value like in a simple php array, which is easy to remember:

```
$node->field_code_used_by[] = $user_id;
```

Comment: How about for entity reference fields that allow multiple values?

Comment: How can I check if a value already exist in the multi value field @4k4 ?

Answer (score 8):

You should be aware of the difference between a single value field and a multiple value field. Code below shows how. Source: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/how-programmatically-update-entity-reference-field-drupal-8

```
$imageIds = [
  '3',
  '32',
  '50'
];
foreach($imageIds as $index => $fid) {
  if($index == 0) {
    $node->set('field_article_images', $fid);
  } else {
    $node->get('field_article_images')->appendItem([
      'target_id' => $fid,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh man I tested this without images and for a single value field and it works too. I found the blog using google I didn't scroll down to your answer.

Comment: This may be a change with later versions of Drupal 8, but I need to include the 'target_type' and 'target_id' to be able to save references to users.

Answer (score 2):

For multi value fields you can use:

```
$node = Node::load(212);
$multi_value = $node->get('field_NAME')->getValue();
$multi_value[] =['target_id' => 101];
$node->set('field_NAME', $multi_value);
$node->save();
```

For single value fields you can use:

```
$node->set('field_NAME',['target_id' => 101]);
```