# Where is the parent/child relationship between nodes stored in the database?

Tags: 8, nodes, database

I am migrating a site from one CMS to Drupal and I'm working on migrating link structures over correctly. This is something I am going to have to automate because there are over 3,500 nodes of content that I am migrating over.

I can't seem to find in Drupal 8's database schema where the relationship between parent and children nodes are stored. I have been looking for something like a 'pid' or a 'cid' column (parent id and child id, respectively), but I can't seem to find a column like that in the schema.

I know you can make nodes children of other nodes, so I know it has to store this information somewhere. If someone could tell me what table and column this information gets stored in I would greatly appreciate that.

[Drupal 8 Database Schema](https://www.drupal.org/files/Drupal8_UPsitesWeb_Schema_10-19-2013.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is, there is none.

Nodes in Drupal does not have a hierarchy, it's other things on top of it that allow you to do that, depending on the use case:

Menu links: You can have menu trees and each points to a node, but the nodes themself don't really about that. Some parts might look like it does, e.g. breadcrumb but that is simply based on the path.

Book module: This allows to create a book (basically a hierarchic structure of nodes), but this only makes sense for specific cases, e.g. structured documentation that has chapters and so on.

References: In many cases, nodes are just *connected* between each other with reference fields, which you could make look like a hierarchy.

Taxonomy: You can have Terms with a hierarchy and reference those from nodes, but again by default that doesn't give you anything hierarchy-like unless you start to combine with with path aliases or so.

=> Content in Drupal is very different from how most other sites handle it and you can't just convert it 1:1.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the `EntityReferenceField`.
To understand more its behavior:

1. Create a content type ('MyTest')
2. Add a `ContentReferenceField` (`EntityReferenceField` on nodes). It machine name could be for example `field_my_reference`.
3. Choose whatever bundle you want a reference to.
4. Create a 'MyTest' element, and add a reference.

Now go to PHPMyAdmin or similar, and start type in the autocomplete field the following:

**node__field_my_reference**

Then you can see the table scheme, and how referencing in the Drupal works in general. There are two main columns:

1. "entity_id" - that is the host entity which has the reference field
2. And the last column of the table "..._target_id", that's the ID to which entity it is referring too

**That being said, I don't recommend you to do this by "hand".** I mean writing SQL queries with exact table names. 
Instead, **use Drupal `EntityTypeManager` when setting up relationships** between two entities (one must have of course an `EntityReferenceField`).

More on that, how to do that programmatically read [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213379/programmatically-update-an-entity-reference-field).