# How to Update Multi Value Entity Reference Field Programatically

Tags: entities, 9

I have two Node Content Types `type_a` and `type_b` I have a field called as `field_author_profile` in `type_a` which is entity reference field to `type_b` with cardinality unlimited.

How do I update `field_author_profile` programatically.

I also need to Check if value already exists in the field , if exists then append the new value while updating the field value or else just assign the value.

I tried the below variants but seems none worked .

```
$author_object->set('field_author_profile', $author_profile_nid);

$author_object->field_author_profile = ['target_id' => $author_profile_nid];

$author_object->field_author_profile->entity->target_id->value = $author_profile_nid;

$author_object->field_author_profile[] = ['target_id' => $author_profile_nid];

$author_object->field_author_profile->target_id = $author_profile_nid;

$author_object->get('field_author_profile')->setValue(['target_id' => $author_profile_nid]);
```

Saved the node after this by using

```
$author_object->save();
```

**Edit** : The field value was not being rendered in the node edit form, even thought it was present in the database. It was due to the wrong bundle type selected in the entity reference field. Once it is corrected it worked as expected.

This was the working solution.

```
$author_object->field_author_profile[] = ['target_id' => $author_profile_nid];
```

Comment: Related https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213379/programmatically-update-an-entity-reference-field

Comment: Your 4th example is the correct one. It’s also the only one not using `field_author_profile`, which could be the problem

Comment: @Clive, Thanks for the response . It was a typo corrected it.